# Securring stored password

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography

Actually I have a database that stores customer sensitive informations.
I'm using something like that to encrypt that data:

```
$algo  = 'AES-256-CTR';
$key ='password md5 from bdd'
$iv   = substr(hash('sha256',$email),0,openssl_cipher_iv_length($algo));

$data = base64_encode($data);
$data = openssl_encrypt($data,$algo,$key,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,$iv);
```

As you see I'm using the customer's email to create the iv and his password md5 for the key.
So if someone hack my bdd he can decrypt the sensitive data.
Is there a better way to do, knowing that my php script needs to be able to decrypt the data for use

My ideas:

-Use a executable on the server that create/modify the password and/or the iv and does the decryption and that the php script calls for that.

-Use a second server that stores the passwords and that the php script needs to call for decryption.

Comment: If someone has access to both your db _and_ your source code (which is really the only way they'd know how to reverse-engineer the 'sensitive data', right), then I'd say you're pretty much boned no matter what.

Comment: @PatrickQ thats usually how I approach it. If they get both, its over, because it means they are all over the server. Game over man, Game over!

Comment: You seem to say that code is not "findable" ? If it is, adding an second server to store the passwords and doing the data decryption should be profitable ?

Comment: If someone got into the server to get the database files directly, they can get the website source code as well. However if someone simply got the *content* of the database (sql injection attacks, other db holes), then they don't necessarily have access to the source code. Hacking into a server is *generally* more difficult than dumping the content of a database through poor use of canned-open-source code libraries etc.

Comment: If someone has access to your source code, then they can see what code is running to connect to your second server. They can then execute these commands and bang, all that effort for nothing.

Comment: @PatrickQ yes sure, I thought about when the get the database without accessing the server, he can "think" about this simple code...

Comment: The counter needs a starting random value, there key and counter starting value combination must never be reused. When passwords are used the key should;d be derived with a function that includes iteration such as PBKDF2. Simply using MD5 is not secure.

Comment: @zaph It's CTR, so a unique nonce (starting bytes of the full counter / IV) is enough. However, using CTR with a static IV is *extremely* dangerous; just logging two values of the encrypted password after a password change is enough to leak large amounts of both the passwords.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use Argon2 to derivate `$key` from user's password, then use Symmetric Encryption like AES, or XSalsa20 or XChacha20 to encrypt it, alternatively you can use other derivation functions that make brute force impractical, just take care that `salt` is never reused, take a look at  [Vault](https://github.com/umbri/Vault), and [libsodium-php](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-php#encrypt-a-file-using-a-key-derived-from-a-password)

Answer (score 0):

> As you see I'm using the customer's email to create the iv and his password md5 for the key.

A few things you may nees to be aware of

- IV suppose to be unique for CTR mode, but as already pointed out, it is static (derived from email).
- it is possible to find md5 collision in a minute on commodity hw (newest tunelling method)
- you are missing any authentication tag.

Common practice for encryption is having random IV, encrypted source and MAC as part of the ciphertext (e. g. iv.encrypted.mac)

imho creating a key from password md5 may be feasible assuming you don't store the keys, so there is nothing to find a collision against and the passwords are having high entropy (are long and random)

> So if someone hack my bdd he can decrypt the sensitive data. Is there a better way to do, knowing that my php script needs to be able to decrypt the data for use

it is generally a problem storing system credentials. you may use a credential vault, but you need to store the vault credentials somewhere. you can encrypt the system credentials, but you need to store the decryption key somewhere.  Ay least hide the credentials from plain sight so it makes more difficult for automated hacking tools or not so dedicated adversaries.